# Update Manager like WSUS

Tags: upgrade, updates, update-manager

Does anyone know how to manage updates in Ubuntu Server, like WSUS does it? For example I want to force Firfox upgrade on all computers (with Ubuntu), which are connected to my corporate network?  I really appreciate any help you can provide.

Comment: You have to use a system management tool like Landscape, Puppet if you want to automate it. Otherwise just SSH to all of them and run `apt-get install firefox`.